# Could two tails work?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design

In the world I am building there are rat-like primates called iolasae, or mane-beast, which are the new world equivalent of great apes. In this family of primates there are sentient humanoid creatures called lokk, They have digitigrade legs, long arms, short legs and prehensile tails. I would like for them to have two [prehensile](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prehensile) tails. Is it possible and if it is how much weight could these tails support?

Comment: Your iolasae must have a serious case of polydactyl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Yes, but..**

...the animal probably won't be very big.

While not a prehensile tail, an elephant's trunk is capable of [lifting 300kg](http://www.elephantsforever.co.za/elephants-faq.html#.VdIimhRVhBc) and it contains no bones whatever.  Note that an elephant's trunk is attached to an absolutely enormous animal of around [4535kg](http://www.elephantsforever.co.za/elephants-faq.html#.VdIimhRVhBc) for a lifting capacity of 6% of body weight.  On the smaller end of the scale, a [spider monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_monkey) is completely capable of holding itself up by it's tail alone. Note that this follows the trend of smaller creatures lifting many times their body weight, such as [ants](http://www.treehugger.com/natural-sciences/ant-weight-lifting-champ-hoists-100x-its-own-weight.html) lifting 100x their body weight.

[image: Spider Monkey]

### **But two!**

An animal could be designed to have large powerful prehensile tail(s) but it would need to be designed that way and supported by an interesting evolutionary history (if your story needs that kind of evidence).  I'm not sure of an examples of an Earth animal with two tails so that will be a very interesting evolutionary history.  There are many instances of Siamese twins that have convergent or divergent spinal columns.  Having two tails is definitely possible, it's just a matter of making them that way.

Comment: This is good because I wanted them to be small. Quick question though, would it need to be light or small?

Comment: @majornorwal are you asking about the animal or the tail?

Comment: The animal would need to be small but the tail itself can be at least as long as the rest of the body.  I saw lots of references to tails as long as the body.  There's probably some math that describes how thick the tail needs to be for a given body weight but I'm not familiar with that kind of math.  I just know it exists.

Comment: I'm talking about the animal

Comment: A smaller/lighter animal is more likely to be able to support it's own body weight with just its tail.

Comment: @TrEs-2b The reason an animal needs to be 'small' is because as one grows bigger their weight, relative to their body size, grows much faster then their muscle strength can (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SquareCubeLaw)  so the reason they need to be small is so that they weight less and their tails can lift, the smaller they they are the lower their weight welative to tail strength.  They have to be light, but light is relative.  if they are rather dense/heavy for their size, but are a small size, they can still be light enough for their tail to lift.